# How to play VOB files on Windows 8 Consumer Preview?

Tags: windows-8-preview, vob

Anybody know, how to play VOB files on Windows 8 Consumer Preview?
You can play DVD disc on W8CP, but if you copy directory VIDEO_TS, and then try to play VTS_01_1,VOB (and so on) as in Windows 7 without any problems works, no chance. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Videolan client aka vlc is available at [videolan website](http://videolan.org/). It plays all sorts of mpeg including mp3, DVD, DVB-S, BluRay and you name it.

Media center would play only DVDs in DVD drive.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually more of players that can do that besides VLC, like [Aimp](http://www.aimp.ru/index.php) or [Media Player classic](http://mpc-hc.org/) and so on, as far as they say in [this article](http://www.askwiki.net/How-to-Play-Vob-Files).

I personally have Aimp and I love it. Works great and with all the formats I can think of.